# Finding a set of values with the binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

For $n  \in \mathbb N$ and the function $p(x) = \left(x + \frac 1x\right)^{n}$.

By the binomial theorem:
$$\left(x + \frac 1x\right)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-k} \left(\frac 1x\right)^{k}$$
**Is that last part right?**

1) For $p(x) = a_ox^{b_o}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{b_n}$ and $D=$ {$b_o, b_1, ..., b_n$}.
Determine D and its maximum and minimum values.

**How can I find the values of D by the binomial theorem? I need some more explanation to understand how... can someone explain it and demonstrate it?**

**Edit:**
Simplification:
$$\left(x + \frac 1x\right)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-2k}$$

Comment: It's easy to see that the power of $x$ in the binomial expansion is $x^{n-2k}$ with $k$ ranging from $0$ to $n$. To start the pattern the terms are $x^n$, $x^{n-2}$, $x^{n-4}$ and so on. Can you see what the elements in $D$ are now?

Comment: $x^{n-k}x^{-k} = x^{n-2k}$ that part is good to me thank you. If I follow the second part, n-2x0, n-2x1, ... n-2xn (since the range of k is from 0 to n) so it should be D = {n, n-2, n-4, ... , -n}. Is that right?

Comment: That is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

We can begin by simplifying the binomial expansion somewhat:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-k} \left(\frac 1x\right)^{k} &= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-2k}\\
&={n \choose 0}x^{n}+{n \choose 1}x^{n-2}+\dots+?\text{ (what's the last term in the sum?)}
\end{align}
$$
Now, just set
$$
p(x) = a_ox^{b_o}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{b_n} = {n \choose 0}x^{n}+{n \choose 1}x^{n-2}+\dots+?
$$

Comment: Then D = {n, n-2, n-4, ... , -n} and minimum is -n and maximum is n. Thanks to you and @CameronWilliams I know fully understand!