# Determine coefficient and give a formula from a set found with the binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

This question is a continuation of: [Finding a set of values with the binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456118/finding-a-set-of-values-with-the-binomial-theorem)

For $n  \in \mathbb N$ and the function $p(x) = \left(x + \frac 1x\right)^{n}$.

By the binomial theorem:
$$\left(x + \frac 1x\right)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-2k}$$

1) For $p(x) = a_ox^{b_o}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{b_n}$ and $D=$ {$b_o, b_1, ..., b_n$}.
Determine D and its maximum and minimum values.
**Answer:** $D = {n, n-2, n-4, ..., -n}$ with a minimum of $-n$ and a maximum of $n$.

2) Determine the coefficient $a_k$ of $x^{b_k}$ where $k=0,1,...,n$ and give a formula.

**Can someone give me a hint of what to do? I don't know where to start for the second part...**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a set of values with the binomial theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456118/finding-a-set-of-values-with-the-binomial-theorem)

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, not a duplicate - it is an extension of that problem.

Comment: Yes it is, another question I asked. Is it ok to rewrite it, or I was suppose to kind of "reopen" my last question?

Comment: No, its okay to ask followup questions as separate questions, but it is always good to make it clear that it is a continuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The question was not clear. The real answer is:
$$a_k={n \choose k}$$
The formula for the $a_k$ coefficient set. Thank you for all the help!

**Old answer:**

The formula is: $f(x)=-x^2+nx+1$.

I found it because:
For example, n=5 so the points will be : 1,5,10,10,5,1 (5 choose 0, 5 choose 1, ..., 5 choose 5). This is a parabola, so I solved it with the parabola function and I got a=-1, b=5 and c=1. If I try with other value, I always got a=-1, b=n and c=1.

Thanks @BrianM.Scott for the great tips!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $x^{b_k}=x^{n-2k}$; what is the coefficient of $x^{n-2k}$?

Comment: I would say 1, is that correct? It is the formula part that I most struggle with... a hint for that part?

Comment: @user2636358: Definitely not $1$. Look at the summation in your question; what's the coefficient of $x^{n-2k}$ in that summation?

Comment: oh! n choose k? so n choose 0, n choose 1, n choose n

Comment: @user2636358: There you go! Yes, that's right.

Comment: And for the formula part, I can see a pattern... for example, n=5 so the coefficient will be : 1,5,10,10,5,1 (5 choose 0, 5 choose 1, ..., 5 choose 5). Or a parabola in a function... from 1 to 2n... do I will go search for "how to find a parabola function" now :P a solve with 3 points in y=ax^2+bx+c

Comment: @user2636358: In general it isn’t a parabola; you really can’t do much more than express it as a binomial coefficient or one of the algebraic equivalents thereor.